# Array of unique JSON values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an array of unique JSON data based on the comparison of a key value.

In this example, I'm trying to remove any objects with duplicate `category` values.

Example:

```
 var products = [
        { category: 'fos', name: 'retek' },
        { category: 'fos', name: 'item' },
        { category: 'nyedva', name: 'blabla' },
        { category: 'fos', name: 'gihi' }
    ];

// array of hold unique values
var uniqueNames = [];

for(i = 0; i< products.length; i++){    
    if(uniqueNames.indexOf(products[i].category) === -1){
        uniqueNames.push(products[i]);        
    }        
}
```

I'm trying to push to the array any object that doesn't have duplicate category values. Here is a live [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/wagipirote/edit?js,console).

Please help!

Comment: Your indexOf checks if uniqueNames already has that category in the array, but as you are pushing the entire object instead of the category, it will never find it and will always push all to the array

Comment: @Kyle so uniqueNames should only contain  `{category:'fos',name:'retek'},{ category:'nyedva',name:'blabla' }`?

Comment: @Moogs Yes, it should only contain those two objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, this is one of them: traverse all the items, and filter out the ones which we have already added with that category. For this we use an object to keep which categories we have seen and which ones are new, so we filter only the seen ones:

```
var seen = {}

var unique = products.filter(function(item){
    if(seen.hasOwnProperty(item.category)){
        return false;
    }else{
        seen[item.category] = true;
        return true;
    }
})

console.log(unique); // only 2 objects
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch

```
for(i = 0; i< products.length; i++){    
    if(uniqueNames.indexOf(products[i].category) === -1){
        uniqueNames.push(products[i]);        
    }        
}
```

To

```
for(i = 0; i< products.length; i++){    
        if(uniqueNames.indexOf(products[i].category) === -1){
            uniqueNames.push(products[i].category);  // Push Name of category. Will now not place duplicates into UnqiueNames     
        }        
    }
```

Console

```
["fos", "nyedva"]
```

Answer (score 0):

When I am trying to do this, I usually put all of the values into a map as keys, since the map data structure will only allow unique keys. So for this case:

```
var crops = [   { 
    id:     0023,
    crop:   "corn"
},
{
    id:     0034,
    crop:   "corn"
},
{
    id:     0222,
    crop:   "wheat"
}
 ];
var cropsMap = {};
for(var i = 0; i < crops.length; i++) {
   cropsMap[crops[i].crop] = true;
}
var uniqueCrops = Object.keys(cropsMap);
```

I made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/KpOmbx) if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
lookup = [];    

for (var product, i = 0; product = products[i++];) {
   var cat = item.category;

   if (!(cat in lookup)) {
     lookup[cat] = 1;
     result.push(products[cat]);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of how your code works.